# what better way to create a dropdown that works with multiline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what better way to create a dropdown that works with multiline in major browsers?

thanks!

Same like this:

```
-------------
- Example 1 -
-   and     -  This is one item
- Example 2 -
-------------
-------------
- Example 3 -
-   and     -  This is another item
- Example 4 -
-------------
-------------
- Example 5 -
-   and     -  and this is another item
- Example 6 -
-------------
```

Give me same help!

Comment: Don't you want to use CSS?

Comment: yes, but how? i have put css for controlrs asp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the

```
<br />
```

html that you would put after each text box?

Comment: is not the best option. controlrs wanted something for asp: textbox or asp: label because they are being created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

`<br />` is one solution. A different approach would be to wrap each control in a div class and apply css to it. Doing it with divs and css will give you much better control over the long run.

```
//css
.coolClass
{
float:left;
}
//EndCss

<div class='coolClass'>
<asp:label>name</asp:label>
<asp:textobox runat='server' id='test1'/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no div because controlrs asp are generated dynamically in my code c #

Comment: Are you generating the html in the backend also? You can use the code behind and response.write to write the html dynamically to the page. If you do that you can write css/javascript/and divs also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx